# Why it takes 19 days to erase a Time Capsule harddisk?

Tags: time-capsule

My [Time Capsule harddisk was dead](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156930/who-to-fix-a-time-capsule-disk-in-internal-disk-needs-repair-status). The problem is, why it takes 19 days to erase it?

[image]

Comment: For clarification... The hard drive in your Time Capsule failed?  Are you just trying to erase it before repair/replacement?  The Mac you're using to erase it, is it connected to the Time Capsule wirelessly or via ethernet?

Comment: When a long process starts, at first the estimates of completion time may be way off.  Wait an hour and see whether the estimate is substantially lower.

Comment: After one and a half day, the orange light is still blinking. The AirPort Utility app does not show any estimation of completion time ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time needed to erase a hard disk depends on the size of the disk, the erasure method (1-pass/3-pass/7-pass) and the number of bad blocks.

If your drive contains bad blocks and you try to erase them, the drive may try numerous times to reread/rewrite the entire block and often invokes the error correction to rebuild the data depending on the erasure method.

Examples:

- 4 weeks ago i had to erase a 320 GB HDD with (finally) 23 bad blocks. It took about 4 hours to finish the task (1-pass).
- 6 month ago i examined a breaking HDD. Every single bad block took 5-10 minutes to be validated.

Furthermore the algorithm estimating the completion time of the erasure will be misguided depending on the position of the bad blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't believe this is the complete answer you would be looking for, there is always the concern of speed of the network and speed of the disk installed in your time capsule.

For the network speed, if you're doing this over WiFi you probably need to consider if you're getting poor performance or high latency. It might not have been noticeable before, but for the large operation you're doing right now it could be killing you. Of course, if you're doing this over wired Ethernet then this bit probably isn't affecting you.

The other bit is disk speed and general filesystem performance. When you're erasing the time capsule, you're not just formatting the disk. Instead, you're erasing the contents of the sparse bundle that is stored on the time capsule disk. The two things that will matter here is 1) you've got a relatively slow hard disk in there (5400 RPM low power variety by default) and 2) the larger the drive and sparse bundle, the longer it is going to take for the job to complete.

I've found that on my NAS, deleting a time machine sparse bundle of nearly 900GB can take most of a day. The problem is that OS X is meticulously going through each individual file inside of this sparse bundle filesystem and deleting them and then updating the various indexes and tables that keep track of what is where. Not that each individual operation is particularly lengthy, but when you actually look inside of a Time Machine sparse bundle you will see probably hundreds of thousands of files and/or references to files which each need to be operated on. It is doing this to keep things neat, tidy and orderly but at the expense of being painfully slow. Frankly, I've found it faster to just delete the sparse bundle container though that can still take a long time.

If why you're doing this is because Time Machine is complaining that there is a problem with the backup and is already in use, you might want to try just rebooting the Time Machine capsule and your Mac and see if that fixes it; it usually seems to in my experience.

Comment: Though you are right with the spin of the hdd, in this case the network speed won't matter at all. The erasure here is NO "file system based" file deletion. It's just a kind of formatting of the Time Capsule HDD.